# Why is Photo on MacBook Pro automatically importing my photos from iPhone?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, photos

I'm not plugging in the USB cable from iPhone to the MacBook. Every time I add new photos on my iPhone, they automatically import to Photos to the MacBook. If I delete them from my MacBook, they also are deleted from my iPhone.

How do I undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have turned on iCloud sync of your Photos on both your MacBook and your iPhone. To stop this from happening, you need to turn this off.

On the MacBook, System Preferences > iCloud. Uncheck the box:

[image]

On the iPhone, Settings > iCloud:

[image]

Comment: do i have to turn off the iCloud sync on both devices, or only one of them? thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: iCloud serves as a Photo repository, replacing any local storage on your machine. On the iPhone, it uses your network connection for transport (cellular or wifi) so you should be careful not to go over your data limit on cellular service or you can potentially incur charges on your next bill. In Settings > Cellular, you can turn off the Photo app from using cellular, and it use wifi when connected.